# Read Excel range as array of text(string representing what is displayed on the screen for the cell)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am trying to read the entire excel data as array of text(The exact same text as displayed in the cell).

I am using this code to convert the excel content to array

`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = excelSheet.get_Range("A1", "P" + excelRowCount);
object[,] values = (object[,])(range.Text);`

but I am getting error like cannot convert DBNull to object[,]

The code will work if I replace `range.Text` with `range.Value` or `range.Value2`
But that won't give the correct data, for example if the data in the cell is 11:00:00 PM the `range.Value` gives 0.95833333333333337
here I need to use `DateTime.FromOADate()` method to convert value 0.95833333333333337 to 11:00:00 PM

But if I go with `excelSheet.Cells[rowNo, columnNo].Text` I will get the correct text, ie:11:00:00 PM, but that will slowdown the process because there are 40K records in the excel sheet.

Is there any way to get the exact text in to array like `object[,] values = (object[,])(range.Value);`, why `range.Text` is not working?

Answer (score 1):

From https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/

> If you try getting .Text from multiple cells into a variant (varr = Range(“A1:A10”).Text) you do NOT get an array of results. Instead if all the cells in the range contain the same value formatted in the same way you get a single formatted value, but if ANY of the cells has different values or formats you get Null ( this could be a useful trick).

That article also concurs with your speed issues with .Text each cell. 
But .Text tries to read a lot of the cell properties(including date formatting which you want) - that's why its slow.

Also be aware that .Text can return ###### if the cell contents don't fit, so you would have to autofit all columns/rows...